# type '...' is not assignable to parameter of type '...' TS 2345

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write this function in my project and I got this error:

```
:Argument of type '(item: HTMLElement) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Element, key: number, parent: NodeListOf<Element>) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'item' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLElement': accessKey, accessKeyLabel, autocapitalize, dir, and 113 more.ts(2345).
```

this is the function:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".choose").forEach(function (item: HTMLElement) {
  item.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    (document.querySelector(".card__timer") as HTMLElement).style.display = "block";
    document
      .querySelectorAll(".card__block:not(.card__timer)")
      .forEach(function (el: HTMLElement) {
        el.style.display = "none";
      });
    startTimer();
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi @nir meir, did the two answers help you with your issue? If so, it would be nice to accept one of them to mark the question as solved. If no, feel free to comment on what's still unclear to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a `NodeList` of [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)s, but your `forEach`-callbacks process [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)s, which are more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the type `HTMLElement` from both `item` and `el` arguments and it should work. Do it like the following:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".choose").forEach(function (item) {
  item.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    (document.querySelector(".card__timer") as HTMLElement).style.display = "block";
    document
      .querySelectorAll(".card__block:not(.card__timer)")
      .forEach(function (el) {
        (el as HTMLElement).style.display = "none";
      });
    startTimer();
  });
});
```

Comment: The (first) error message is about the `item` argument (but you've also removed that one's type declaration).